# One of me Gmail accounts is being hacked; how can I inform Google?

Tags: gmail, google-account, security

I think one of my Google accounts is being attacked because without my desire `G-XXX` codes are being sent to my phone via SMS. I want to know which email is this code for and want to inform Google for further assistance. how should I reach google and ask them these?

Answer (score 1):

According to catzrule [answer](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/gmail/T8fUoABwMpo/YsUPyHfBDAAJ) to 
"Suspicious "Unusual Activity" text - if spam, where should I report?"

> Text (sms) is not something that Google could help with.  Maybe your
>   phone company?
>
> Certainly sounds like a phishing attempt;  others may correct me here.
>
> Many sms clients on phones have a "block" feature.  Long press on the
>   message and see if you have that option.

That post is from 2016. If you want to make your own post go to https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/gmail

In either case, it worth to check if you have in place all the security measures suggested by Google on [Secure an account that has suspicious activity](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7539929?hl=en&ref_topic=3382255)